# Take a folder of PDF files and convert them to CSV and save them in another folder with the same name but ending with csv

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to take a folder of existing pdfs and copy and convert the copy to csv and save in a different file location...

the hierarchy is as follows:

Users/.../Test/PDF
Users/.../Test/CSV

I then want to take all the CSV files and add the file name to the first column, then append all of them together while deleting redundant blank lines that will be determined by column B that either has integers in them or otherwise they are deleted.

Here is the code that I have so far:

```
import os
from pathlib import Path
import csv
import tabula
import shutil

statis = []

pdf_folder = Path("/Users/bensorensen/Documents/Test/PDF/")
csv_folder = Path("/Users/bensorensen/Documents/Test/CSV/")

pdf_files = pdf_folder.glob('*.pdf')

for pdf in pdf_files:
    if item.endswith('pdf'):
        tabula.convert_into(df, output, output_format="csv", stream = True, pages='all')

shutil.move(pdf_folder,csv_folder)
```

Any help or additional eyes would be most appreciated.

Comment: Your code is mixing solutions.  tabula can convert each file into a pandas dataframe, so you can manipulate it before writing.  That's `tabula.read_pdf`.  Or, tabula can convert the PDF file to a CSV file, which you can then read and process.  That's `tabula.convert_into`.  Or, tabula can convert the whole directory in a batch, which you can process later, `tabula.convert_into_by_batch`.  Each has advantages and disadvantages.  Your folder move won't work because the PDF folder already exists.  Are you sure you want CSV files in a folder called PDF?

Comment: No I want the  CSV files to be moved into the CSV folder

Comment: I have updated my code so it looks like it is working but the CSV files are being copied into the PDF folder...as you thought they would, how do I get them moved into the CSV folder? any ideas?